# How can day-level tasks depend on hour-level tasks when using Airflow

Tags: airflow

Our company has many different kinds of tasks to run every day,Some tasks are hour level, and some tasks are day level.The day-level tasks depend on the hour-level tasks of the past 24 hours，how can airflow meet the demand.I've looked through the official documents but don't find the answer.

Comment: are you asking if airflow fits your requirement or not?

Comment: Yes,I wonder if there is such a feature in airflow,and how is the best way to handle my situation.

Comment: airflow can cater to such requirement but I do recommend some research at your end